# AWS Glue with Official SFTP Connector

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-marketplace

I'm currently trying to import Files from an SFTP server using AWS Glue with the official SFTP Connector from the [Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-ef5tj7wmzj3hu?applicationId=GlueStudio&ref_=beagle&sr=0-1&stl=true#pdp-usage)

I configurated it, gave it a secret as required, and started it. I'm using the visual console to create the glue scripts but here is the generated one:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node SFTP Connector for AWS Glue 3.0
SFTPConnectorforAWSGlue30_node1688135479601 = (
    glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        connection_type="marketplace.spark",
        connection_options={
            "path": "~/haproxy",
            "fileFormat": "text",
            "connectionName": "SFTP-Glue-3",
        },
        transformation_ctx="SFTPConnectorforAWSGlue30_node1688135479601",
    )
)

# Script generated for node S3 bucket
S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=SFTPConnectorforAWSGlue30_node1688135479601,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="json",
    connection_options={"path": "s3://s8-glue-test-bucket2", "partitionKeys": []},
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node3",
)

job.commit()
```

I've tried the Glue 4.0 Component just like I use the Glue 3.0 Component.
According to logs it is able to retrieve secrets and all but as soon as it tries to connect some `NullPointerException` occurs.

Heres the last log line before connection:

```
2023-06-30T15:54:31.067+02:00   23/06/30 13:54:31 INFO SFTPConnectionPoolV2: Read key file and connect
```

Here are the Logs:

```
23/06/30 13:54:31 ERROR ProcessLauncher: Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/Sync SFTP.py", line 16, in <module>
    SFTPConnectorforAWSGlue40_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 609, in from_options
    return self._glue_context.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type,
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 232, in create_dynamic_frame_from_options
    source = self.getSource(connection_type, format, transformation_ctx, push_down_predicate, **connection_options)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 104, in getSource
    j_source = self._ssql_ctx.getSource(connection_type,
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o89.getSource.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.marketplace.connector.sftp.SFTPTableProvider.packPath(SFTPTableProvider.java:199)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.marketplace.connector.sftp.SFTPTableProvider.getDataSource(SFTPTableProvider.java:136)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.marketplace.connector.sftp.SFTPTableProvider.inferSchema(SFTPTableProvider.java:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.getTableFromProvider(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.loadV2Source(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:209)
    at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:171)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.marketplace.connector.CustomDataSourceFactory$.loadSparkDataSource(CustomDataSourceFactory.scala:89)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.marketplace.connector.CustomDataSourceFactory$.loadDataSource(CustomDataSourceFactory.scala:33)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getCustomSource(GlueContext.scala:176)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getCustomSourceWithConnection(GlueContext.scala:483)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getSourceInternal(GlueContext.scala:975)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getSource(GlueContext.scala:783)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```